# Return all Fields and Distinct Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Whats the best way to do this, when looking for distinct rows?

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, address 
  FROM table;
```

I still want to return all fields, ie address1, city etc but not include them in the DISTINCT row check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not mix and match your city, state, etc. and should give you the last one added even:

```
select b.*
from (
    select max(id) id, Name, Address
    from table a
    group by Name, Address) as a
inner join table b
on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Then you have to decide what to do when there are multiple rows with the same value for the column you want the distinct check to check against, but with different val;ues in the other columns. In this case how does the query processor know which of the multiple values in the other columns to output, if you don't care, then just write a group by on the distinct column, with Min(), or Max() on all the other ones..

EDIT: I agree with comments from others that as long as  you have multiple dependant columns in the same table (e.g., Address1, Address2, City, State ) That this approach is going to give you mixed (and therefore inconsistent ) results.  If each column attribute in the table is independant ( if addresses are all in an Address Table and only an AddressId is in this table) then it's not as significant an issue... cause at least all the columns from a join to the Address table will generate datea for the same address, but you are still getting a more or less random selection of one of the set of multiple addresses...

Answer (score 1):

When you have a mixed set of fields, some of which you want to be DISTINCT and others that you just want to appear, you require an *aggregate query* rather than DISTINCT. DISTINCT is only for returning single copies of *identical fieldsets*. Something like this might work:

```
SELECT name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT address) AS addresses, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT city) AS cities
FROM the_table
GROUP BY name;
```

The above will get one row for each name. `addresses` contains a comma delimted string of all the addresses for that name once. `cities` does the sames for all the cities.

However, I don't see how the results of this query are going to be useful.  It will be impossible to tell which address belongs to which city.

If, as is often the case, you are trying to create a query that will output rows in the format you require for presentation, you're much better off accepting multiple rows and then processing the query results in your application layer.

Comment: +1 for the insight that SQL doesn't have to do everything for you.  This solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can do</strike>

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Address, Max (Address1), Max (City)
FROM table
```

Use @JBrooks answer below. He has a better answer.

[Return all Fields and Distinct Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492431/return-all-fields-and-distinct-rows/1492610#1492610)

Comment: Cool Thanks. Thanks everyone else. This is what I was after. 
SELECT name,Max(address),Max(city),Max(state),Max(zip),Max(tel),Max(fax) FROM Locations GROUP BY name;

Comment: This is what you want?  If you have 2 rows for a given name Wilm, DE and Newark, Pa  this would return Wilm, PA

Comment: @JBrooks is right, you will get incorrect values by using MAX or MIN or any aggregate function for that matter. You really should determine what should happen in case of duplicates and apply that logic.

Comment: @MadPhp: I would go with @JBrooks answer below. I upvoted him myself. The only thing I dont like in his code is the use of a, b, c as aliases, but other than that, I would actually have done what he has stated.

Comment: there was duplicate address but with different ZIP codes. The different zips where added so people could return the same centre, if they where in zip codes close by. So it all cool. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this because it doesn't really make sense.

```
name | address | city | etc...
abc  | 123     | def  | ...
abc  | 123     | hij  | ...
```

if you were to include city, but not have it as part of the distinct clause, the value of city would be unpredictable unless you did something like Max(city).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or above you can use the RowNumber function. This will get you the row with the lowest ID for each name. If you want to 'group' by more columns, add them in the PARTITION BY section of the RowNumber.

```
SELECT id, Name, Address, ...
(select id, Name, Address, ...,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY id) AS RowNo
  from table) sub
WHERE RowNo = 1
```